# build error about AllJoyn in Xcode 5.1.1(alljoyn/Version.h can't find)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, alljoyn

I'm refer "AllJoyn Programming Guide for the Objective-C Language" Document.
[document is here](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/alljoyn/docsdownloads/ios-and-osx)

But when I build basic code, It will show

```
/myroot/alljoyn-14.02.00-osx_ios-sdk/alljoyn_objc/AllJoynFramework/AllJoynFramework/AJNVersion.mm:17:9: 'alljoyn/Version.h' file not found
```

I had put AllJoyn SDK and OpenSSL file in the folder and setting some property based on the document.

[image]
[image]
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Have any one know how to resolve the problem?

I fell It's not find the AllJoyn iOS SDK Framework, but I had setting based on this document.

Thank you very much.

-- renew--

my header search path
[image]

It's my data folder structure
[image]

Comment: Can you add the header path in project settings and check

Comment: I had add header search path. I had renew my content photo, you can see the photo

Comment: Have you included the path $(ALLJoyn)/alljoyn_core/build/darwin/arm/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/$(CONFIGURATION)/dist/cpp/inc
$(ALLJoyn)/alljoyn_core/build/darwin/arm/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/$(CONFIGURATION)/dist/cpp/inc/alljoyn

Comment: Hope this links helps http://andreamazz.github.io/blog/2014/01/25/configuring-alljoyn-on-ios/

Comment: I had add path in header search paths
$(ALLJOYN_ROOT)/core/alljoyn/build/darwin/arm/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/$(CONFIGURATION)/dist/cpp/inc $(ALLJOYN_ROOT)/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/AllJoynFramework/AllJoynFramework/

I will check your link.

Comment: Did you have build complete on iOS before? thanks :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had find the problem. The problem is header search path not correct. When I set environment variable by terminal. I was not restart xcode . So there are still not find header file.

Comment: hi, i install alljoyn but always not file file "#import "alljoyn/Translator.h", i used to xcode 8. thanks